# Building a header only framework for iOS with Bazel (to be consumed by a native iOS implementation)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cmake, bazel

## Summary

I am currently trying to build a **header only** C++ (17) library for iOS. This library should output a .framework which should be consumable in a standard iOS application. The library also (of course) has other dependencies which do have source files.

## Background

- The existing setup uses Bazel, and up until this point has been using Tulsi for integration, but now this needs to change to versioned library releases (unless Tulsi can generate an iOS .framework complete with header files which I have not seen yet - please educate me if it exists).
- Using initially `ios_framework` from the [build_bazel_rules_apple](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_apple/blob/master/doc/rules-ios.md), until it was made clear in the documentation that this should only be used within a Bazel ios target (i.e. using the `ios_application`) and that this can't then be taken out and used separately within another project.
- I then turned towards `ios_static_framework` (also seen in [build_bazel_rules_apple](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_apple/blob/master/doc/rules-ios.md)) which seems to be the correct thing, however I can never get it to maintain the header structure.

## Currently

### Bazel

Using `ios_static_framework` requires (apparently) first wrapping the normal `cc_library` with an `objc_library`, which can then be put in the `deps` of the `ios_static_framework` i.e.

```
# BUILD example (assume all rules are loaded and WORKSPACE is setup correctly)
cc_library(
 name = "somelib",
 deps = [
  "//otherlib0", # A sub part of the lib I am trying to build
  "//otherlib1" # Another sub part of the lib I am trying to build
 ],
 hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
 visibility=["//visibility:public"]
)

objc_library(
 name = "somelibwrapperobjc",
 deps = [
  "//:somelib"
 ],
 hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
 visibility=["//visibility:public"]
)

ios_static_framework(
 name = "somelibidealoutput",
 families = ["iphone"],
 hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
 umbrella_header = "libheader.h",
 deps = [
  "//:somelibwrapperobjc"
 ]
)
```

It appears to also build without the cc_library step to the same affect and the output is a directory with a `somelibidealoutput.framework` and the header file `libheader.h` but everything else is gone.

So this ^^ doesn't work.

### CMake

So then I tried with CMake from scratch.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(myproject C CXX)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/projectincludesadditional)
set(HEADER_FILES
    myheader1.hpp
    onelayer/myheader2.hpp
    additional/header/myheader3.hpp
    ...
)
```

I then attempting the next part in two different ways. Since CMake header only libraries are simple I tried:

```
add_library(mylibrary INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(mylibrary INTERFACE ${HEADER_FILES})
```

Which could then be linked to the actual library, as well as the other alternative:

```
add_library(myconsuminglibrary SHARED
 ${HEADER_FILES})
```

The framework can then be built using the following:

```
set_target_properties(myconsuminglibrary PROPERTIES
 FRAMEWORK TRUE
 FRAMEWORK_VERSION CXX
 LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
 MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.something.idontcare
 MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST info.plist
 VERSION 16.4.0
 SOVERSION 1.0.0
 PUBLIC_HEADER "myuselessumbrellaheaderthatdoesntpullanyotherheadersin.hpp"
 XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
)
```

But the headers don't copy across! only the specified public *umbrella* header does (and even if there's an include in there it won't copy that across since it's not lexing the file.

I followed a possible solution [here (on cmake)](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16739) in the suggested comments but it seems to just copy one layer deep and again removes the file structure.

Should I just be using a simple `install` and assuming thats the best way for these headers to then be used in a framework? Essentially copy them and hope for the best?

### Xcode

Finally, I tried to make a traditional xcode framework starting from scratch in xcode.

I managed to get everything to build as expected (with minimal changes), but this required path changes to the xcode project etc.

However, it flattens the hierarchy of the headers and therefore all relative header paths once again become useless in the consuming application/library.

## Question

1. **Can a header only C++ library be compiled into a dynamic/static library for iOS?**
2. **If so, which build system & which config changes are needed to my CMake/Bazel build system?**
3. **Any other suggestions??**

Comment: If this is a header only library, why do you feel the need to make this a framework?

Comment: @MobileBen because it has dependencies which aren't header only, and therefore those dependencies should be built in otherwise any consumer of the header only library will also require all of these dependencies every time the consumer wants to build their library.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought. How do you plan on distributing this? Github? Pods? Carthage? Don't care? I am assuming you just want to find a solution to build the dependencies and package what is needed. Do you plan on installing things into `/usr/local`?

Comment: The idea is that once it is built it becomes a binary which can be versioned. This binary can then be called in most likely through pods, but could in theory be any system.

Comment: Let's say your header only lib is A. And it has dependencies B and C. Is your objective to create a "binary" that has A, B, and C? And is B and C already a Pod? I'm asking these to better understand what you are trying to do. I'm predominantly a C++ guy that works in iOS. So I do incorporate a lot of C++ libs in my code. Header only libraries need to be compiled into the application. They can be compiled into a lib/framework, but that is for that library/framework's usage of the header only lib.

Comment: One other thing, are these dependencies C++ as well?